# *BASH* "Not a valid identifier" and "Syntax error : EOF"

Tags: bash

The following code is meant to create a user profile using bash script (I am a complete beginner by the way) and I can't quite figure out the problem with my code. I am getting the error "not a valid identifier" for the variables when taking input using read -p. I am also having trouble with ending the file as I am getting the error "syntax error: unexpected end of file".

```
read -p "Please enter a username : " username
read -p "Please enter a password : " password
egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    echo "$username already exists!"
    exit 1
else
    pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $password)
    useradd -m -p $pass $password
    [ $? == 0 ] && echo "User had been succesfully created and added to system group" || echo "Failed to create and add user to system group"
    exit 2
fi
```

Thanks!

Comment: try using `set -e` . Also dumb question since there's no `#!/bin/bash` you are running this as bash correct? Sometimes other interpreters can have weird side effects

Comment: Try the example they use [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html) instead use echo and read. It could be something with read -p. Or are you getting the error when trying to place the user using useradd?

Comment: The error still occurs when using echo and read.

Comment: Use `getent` to retrieve records from `/etc/passwd` -- that'll work even with LDAP or NIS or other stores. And there's no reason whatsoever to expect perl's `crypt()` to be the same algorithm your local PAM modules are configured to use.

Comment: Also, you've got a bunch of bugs from missing quoting; http://shellcheck.net/ will find those automatically.

Comment: that said, the other bugs you ask about in this question aren't actually caused by the code you included -- which is to say that this question is incomplete, thus nonanswerable.

Comment: Does this script have DOS line endings?

Comment: @EtanReisner, good call, almost certainly correct -- if this question were scoped to the `read` failures, I'd call it worthy (at least of a close-as-duplicate of one of the many preexisting questions about the same error case).

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

1. Remember to add the [hashbang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))
2. Use `-q` flag to suppress output of `egrep`
3. Comments (and the man pages) suggests that encrypting the password with `crypt` might not be such a bright idea. Instead use the system `passwd` to add the password for the user

The man pages for `useradd` with regards to the `-p` flag:

> Note: This option is not recommended because the password (or
>   encrypted password) will be visible by users listing the processes.
>
> You should make sure the password respects the system's password
>   policy.

I think your main problem was passing the unencrypted password as the username to the `useradd` command, the following works:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -r -p "Please enter a username : " username
egrep -q "^$username" /etc/passwd
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    printf "\n%s already exists!\n" "$username"
    exit 1
else
    useradd -m "$username" && passwd "$username"
    if [ $? == 0 ]; then
        printf "\nUser had been succesfully created and added to system group\n"
    else
        printf "\nFailed to create and add user to system group\n"
        exit 2
    fi
fi
```

Comment: "Works" only for a very limited value of. Try a password with spaces, or starting with a dash, or on a system where the local PAM configuration uses a different hash algorithm than perl's `crypt()`.

Comment: ...also, `foo && bar || baz` is not a ternary operator, and should not be used as one: its semantics are **not** identical to `if foo; then bar; else baz; fi`. Look at what happens if `bar` fails -- that can happen even with `printf`, for instance if stdout is closed. (It'll *always* happen here, since your first is typo'd as `printg`)

Comment: Also, look at what happens if the username contains regex characters -- if it has `.`s in it, for instance, then those will be treated as single-character wildcards, so other users' names can match the `egrep`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the comments. What about adding a user without a password and then setting it with `passwd`?

Comment: (also, instead of `foo; if [ $? == 0 ]; then...`, just do `if foo; then...`

Comment: re: the two-stage add-then-set, whether `passwd` will accept content except from the TTY varies per platform. You still have quoting-related bugs, btw. `"$username"`, not `$username` -- which http://shellcheck.net/ will catch.

Comment: Also, the string comparison operator inside `[ ]` is `=`, not `==` -- see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html. Bash allows `==` as an extension, but it's not portable.